# Forbid the access to the connect page when user is already logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I made an app with Rails 4 where the users can access to the website only if they are logged. I didn't use Devise to do that but I've followed [this railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch). It works well but I have a problem, when an user is logged he can still go to the log in page, I want that when he try to go to the log in page he is redirected to the home page, but I didn't find the way to do this.

**Session controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  if @current_user.nil?
    render :layout => false
  else
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Vous êtes déjà connecté"
  end
end

  #Connexion
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user 
      if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token  
    end
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Bienvenue !"
    else
      redirect_to :connect, :notice => "E-mail ou mot de passe incorrect"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to :connect, :notice => "Déconnecté !"
  end
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

I tried to put a if inside my `new`action and check if there is a current user but it doesn't work

Comment: Where do you define `@current_user`? Can you show the code?

Comment: `redirect_to root_url if current_user` put this line at the top of `new` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using `current_user` and not `@current_user`. The value of `@current_user` is `nil` before the first time you call `current_user`. I would recommend using a `before_action`:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :ensure_no_current_user, only: [:new]

  def new
    render :layout => false
  end

  private

  def ensure_no_current_user
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Vous êtes déjà connecté"
      false
    end 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to railscast you have mentioned, there is no variable like `@current_user`. Instead, `current_user` is a method that lets you know whether a user is logged in or not.

`@current_user` has been defined in `current_user` method, but you can not access in other methods. So you just need to use the method `current_user` as follows:

```
def new
  redirect_to root_url if current_user
  # other code
end
```

Comment: It could worked but I need to set render :layout => false and Rails doesn't accept a redirect and a render